# How to use new slds charts in lightning componets

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, slds

I could see that, salesforce release new feature in SLDS charts under Design Guidelines.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/charts/

I cannot see any explanation of how we can use these charts in lightning components. Did anyone try it? Please share your inputs.
Thanks !!!

Comment: I think you need to download the kit to do more

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand your question, so thank you for your patience if I miss the mark. The Design Guidelines provide design principles for creating or implementing charts. They do not provide the actual code or functionality.

Comment: Hi Lise, Thanks for your input," Design Guidelines provide design principles for creating or implementing charts". so I want to use the same principle for lightning charts.So I need to refer in SLDS or third party libraries, because of lightning locker services there are some issues with third party libraries. So I thought salesforce introduced its own chart libraries.

Comment: SLDS UX experts released guidelines for using other libraries, or creating your own chart functionality, to ensure you create an experience consistent with SLDS and achieve full accessibility. We are not providing any chart libraries at this time. I hope you still find them helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the input, Chart.js works for me. I need to explore the Design Guidelines.